# DEPRECATION WARNING: implicit join references. Rails don't want to be a SQL parser for includes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am upgrading an old app from rails3 to rails 4. Currently on rails 4.0

I have a lot of such deprecation warnings while running rspec:

```
  Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and 
knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading 
comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a 
full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to 
write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, 
you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a 
table from a string:

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 
'foo'").references(:comments)

If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the 
feature entirely by setting 
`config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. 

 DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) 
 (one of: product_masters, product_master_names) that are referenced 
 in a string SQL snippet. For example: 

Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
```

Here is the lines that causing error

```
def find_product_master
    masters = ProductMaster.includes(:product_master_names).where("gcc = 1 and crossed_product_master_id is null and product_masters.supplier_id is null && (product_masters.slug = :name or product_masters.slug = :clean_name or product_master_names.slug = :name or product_master_names.slug = :clean_name) and product_masters.color = :color and (product_subfamily_id = :subfamily_id or second_product_subfamily_id = :subfamily_id)", name: line.file_name.parameterize, clean_name: line.file_name.parameterize.gsub("chateau","").parameterize, color: line.file_color, subfamily_id: line.product_subfamily_id)
    masters.size == 1 ? line.update_column(:product_master_id, masters.first.id) : line.update_column(:status, "product_master_missing")
end
```

I tried like it was described in warning

```
 def find_product_master
    masters = ProductMaster.includes(:product_master_names).where("gcc = 1 and crossed_product_master_id is null and product_masters.supplier_id is null && (product_masters.slug = :name or product_masters.slug = :clean_name or product_master_names.slug = :name or product_master_names.slug = :clean_name) and product_masters.color = :color and (product_subfamily_id = :subfamily_id or second_product_subfamily_id = :subfamily_id)".references(:product_master_names), name: line.file_name.parameterize, clean_name: line.file_name.parameterize.gsub("chateau","").parameterize, color: line.file_color, subfamily_id: line.product_subfamily_id)
    masters.size == 1 ? line.update_column(:product_master_id, masters.first.id) : line.update_column(:status, "product_master_missing")
 end
```

But then i received an error

```
 NoMethodError:
    undefined method `references' for #<String:0x00000010f2c730>
```

Comment: Can you cut this thing down to size, a more minimal version that reproduces your problem? I'm losing my mind trying to figure out what's going on as I have to scroll to see anything.

Comment: problem comes from the line
`masters = ProductMaster.includes(:product_master_names).where("...")`
The warning i have tells: 
`It looks like you are eager loading table(s)  that are referenced 
 in a string SQL snippet` 
The warning also says i just need to `.references(:my_table)` for fix.
But after adding this into that line, i receive `undefined method `references' for #<String:0x00000010f2c730>`

Comment: Make sure you're chaining `references` on to the end of the scope and no to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain `references` behind the `include` call instead of calling `reference` on a one of the parameter of `where`:

```
masters = ProductMaster
  .includes(:product_master_names)
  .references(:product_master_names)
  .where(
    # ...
  )
```

Comment: I will be able to test in 4 hours, but it's strange for me. If you look at warning, you can see it gives me an example how to fiz, and reference is after string. Anyway, i will try, thx

Comment: The order is not important. You can chain the `reference` after the `where` too. But you called `reference` on an argument of the `where` call. And that led to the error `undefined method 'references' for #<String...`